# How to change css style for fb-recommendations box?

Tags: css, facebook-recommendations

I need to change font-size and link color to implement the fb-recommendations box in our website. Unfortunately, I cannot influence this by using the widget creator. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

The only options for customizing those plugins are those listed when you generate the code for the plugin. Cross-domain restrictions limit CSS from your site modifying the plugins appearance.